# Should memory not declining considered as memory leak?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, java-11

I have 3 pods in kubernetes written in springboot. The max memory allocated is 1.5 GB. The container during some load scaled to 3 from inital 2. Now the memory usage in each POD is 1GB. But even during non peak hours the scale down is not happening.The memory usage is consistent in 3 pods with almost 1GB usage.

The application uses Java 11 and the GC of Java 11 seems to be G1 which might not be doing a full memory freeing. Could memory leak be a reason its not going down or because of G1 GC.
But if its memory leak it shouldn't be stable and keeps on increasing?

Can anyone tell me what exactly could be happening in these scenario?

Comment: Why do you expect the memory to go down?

Comment: @Holger Because when the load goes low, the resources gets released and GC would do free the heap space, so the memory usage should decrease.

Comment: But that’s not how garbage collection works. The garbage collector will run when your application needs memory, not when the load is low. So it boils down to the opposite. When the load is low, there is no need for memory, hence, the garbage collector does not run.

Comment: Unless you explicitly execute a full GC run via `System.gc()` G1GC will not release memory to the OS.